# How to show grid with zoom lower than 35%

Tags: scribus

I'm making a poster in "A0" format.
When I zoom out to 35% and below, the grid disappears.

It's a shame because of the size of the document I often need to work at low zoom to have an overview.

Is there a way to force scribus to show grid under 35% zoom?

Below are two screenshot, the first is at 36% (grid shown) and second 35% (grid not shown):

[image: Scribus A0 36% (grid shown)]

[image: Scribus A0 35% (grid not shown)]

**EDIT**:

I mistakenly used the word "guides" to speak about "grid". I now corrected my question.

Comment: Which version of Scribus are you using and on which platform?

I see the guides at any small % in both 1.5.x and 1.4.x on Linux...

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Xenial, I use scribus 1.4.6 installed from official Ubuntu apt repo.

Comment: @a.l.e Sorry, i just figured out i mistakenly used the word "guides" to speak about grid". I edited my question

Comment: I know that it's hard to be told "do not do it", but I would suggest you simply not to use the grid. The grid is a tool that is mostly useful for vector drawing. For page layout, you should consider creating a set of guides.  I don't know if it's even worth to write a bug report for this misbehavior.

Comment: @a.l.e Thanks for your suggestion. As you said i managed to not use it.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this behavior for the grid is present in Scribus 1.5.x. However, the baseline grid and guides (which are probably more important for most Scribus uses) are visible at any zoom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thoughts, I would say that -- given the characteristics of the grid in Scribus -- the behavior is correct.

While in Inkscape the grid "grows" and "shrinks" when you zoom in and out, in Scribus it has a fixed spacing and:

- Scribus basically cannot scale the grid lines when you zoom in without painting the whole area with the grid's color
- You cannot snap to the grid points when they are so close and you should disable the grid when zooming in at very low levels.

I'm not sure either that a more flexible grid spacing should be added to Scribus (I would rather vote for completely removing the grid from Scribus...).

The grid is a tool that is useful for vector drawing, but in page layout you will probably profit by defining and using guides.

Comment: From now on i will use guides.

Comment: Nice! Have fun with Scribus!